# Initializing and appending Nested Lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

While trying to append values to a nested list through a for loop,  I came across an issue that the appending values to the list depends on the way the list is initialized.Suppose, I initialize a nested array as:

```
    a=[[[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[],[]]]
    a[0][1].append(2)
```

results in

```
    [[[], [2], [], []], [[], [], [], [], []]]
```

but initializing and appending data in the following manner

```
    a= [[[]]*4]*2
    a[0][1].append(2)
```

results in

```
    [[[2], [2], [2], [2]], [[2], [2], [2], [2]]]
```

What is the difference between the two as both of them initialize the same type of list?

Comment: When using asterisk `*` it multiplies the empty list into many. So when appending, all the lists that are multiplied, gets appended

Comment: `[x]*n` creates a list with *n references to the same object*. Copies aren't made. So, `x = []`, then `a = [x, x, x]`, then try `a[0].append(2)` and see the result

Comment: When you do the following:

 ``a=[[[],[],[],[]],[[],[],[],[],[]]]
        a[0][1].append(2)
       # result - > 
    [[[], [2], [], []], [[], [], [], [], []]]``
it results in the above because you are taking the 0th element of list a and then appending 2 at the 1st location.


but doing something like this

    ``a = []*3``

will create a 3 elements in the list a

``a = [ , , ]``

similarly if you do something like this

    ``a = [10]*3``

it will create 

    ``a = [10, 10, 10]``

Comment: Got it. Thanks. But is there a way to get around it?

Comment: `[[[] for _ in range(4)] for _ in range(2)]`